# How to use the ROUND or TRUNC function while also dividing

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue when dividing by keeping the result set as 4 digits only.

I have tried round, trunc and cast without getting the desired result

```
          trunc(stg4.std_deviation/NULLIF(stg4.avg_sls_13,0) * 100,4) as CV1,
          round((stg4.std_deviation/NULLIF(stg4.avg_sls_13,0)) * 100,4) as CV2,
          round(stg4.std_deviation,4)/NULLIF(round(stg4.avg_sls_13,4),0) * 100 as CV3
```

The result of CV1 is -6.27052173913043E41

The result of CV2 is -6.27052173913043E41

The result of CV3 is NULL

My desired result would be the closest number to the limit NUMBER (12,4) datatype I have for the column

Comment: What about the `E41`?

Comment: Does that mean exponential? Which would mean it is actually a larger number than -6. If so, my limitation is NUMBER(12,4) how do I keep it within that range

Comment: . . Yes.  It means the number is actually  -62,705,217,391,304,300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000, give or take a zero or two.

Answer (score 0):

Would `TO_CHAR` with scientific notation help?

```
SQL> with temp (col) as
  2    (select -6.27052173913043E41 from dual)
  3  select to_char(col, '9d0000EEEE') result
  4  from temp;

RESULT
------------
 -6,2705E+41

SQL>
```

Comment: That doesn't help as the limitation for that column is NUMBER(12,4). How do I keep it at the maximum possible number within that range and precision?